# Parsing plain text with AWK regex tools

Tags: regex, parsing, awk

I have a physics problem in Indonesian:

> Dari salah satu bagian gedung yang tingginya 20 m, dua buah batu
>   dijatuhkan secara berurutan. Massa kedua batu masing-masing 1/2 kg dan
>   5 kg. Bila percepatan gravitasi bumi di tempat itu g = 10 m/s2,
>   tentukan waktu jatuh untuk kedua batu itu (Abaikan gesekan udara)

Translation in English as below(from [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Dari%20salah%20satu%20bagian%20gedung%20yang%20tingginya%2020%20m,%20dua%20buah%20batu%20dijatuhkan%20secara%20berurutan.%20Massa%20kedua%20batu%20masing-masing%201/2%20kg%20dan%205%20kg.%20Bila%20percepatan%20gravitasi%20bumi%20di%20tempat%20itu%20g%20=%2010%20m/s2,%20tentukan%20waktu%20jatuh%20untuk%20kedua%20batu%20itu%20%28Abaikan%20gesekan%20udara%29)):

> From one of the building at the height of 20 m, two rocks are dropped.
>   The second mass of stone each 1/2 kg and 5 kg. If the acceleration of
>   gravity at the g = 10 m/s2, determine the time it fell to the second
>   stone (Ignore air friction)

I want this problem parsed into this form:

```
Height = 20 m
Mass A = 1/2 kg 
Mass B = 5 kg
Gravity = 10 m/s2
```

Until now, I have only two form of code. This is the first:

**#only take the numbers**

```
{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){          
    if($i ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/)       
    print $i                 
  }
}
```

**#only take the units**

```
{  
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){                     
  if(($i ~ /^m\/s2/) || ($i ~ /^kg$/) || ($i ~ /^m$/))      
      print $i  
  }
}
```

Now, how to join these two of awk code? I have made joint like this:

```
BEGIN { FS = "[, ]+" }  

#taking units

{  
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){                     
  if(($i ~ /^m\/s2/) || ($i ~ /^kg$/) || ($i ~ /^m$/))      
      print $i                                  
  }
}

#taking numbers

{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){          
    if($i ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/) 
      print $i              
  }
}
```

But code above results in this output:

```
master@master:~/Dokumen/Pelajaran/Semester 4/Pak Anom$ awk -f plasma.awk soal1 
m
20
kg
m/s2
1/2
5
10
master@master:~/Dokumen/Pelajaran/Semester 4/Pak Anom$
```

At least, I want the result be like this:

```
20 m
1/2 kg 
5 kg 
10 m/s2
```

I wanna use this awk code as basis for physic exercise/problem into automatic calculation so this basis is very crucial for me. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not _entirely_ convinced that an Indonesian Physics problem parser  is likely to be of general use to the programming community :-)

Comment: @DannyBee: [tag:regex] is good, but why do you keep adding [tag:perl] and [tag:sed] tags when the OP says he wants to use [tag:awk]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/[,.]/,"",$(i+1))
        if($i~/^[[:digit:]]/) {
            print $i,$(i+1)
        }
    }
}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
Dari salah satu bagian gedung yang tingginya 20 m, dua buah batu dijatuhkan secara berurutan. Massa kedua batu masing-masing 1/2 kg dan 5 kg. Bila percepatan gravitasi bumi di tempat itu g = 10 m/s2, tentukan waktu jatuh untuk kedua batu itu (Abaikan gesekan udara)

$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/[,.]/,"",$(i+1))
        if($i~/^[[:digit:]]/) {
            print $i,$(i+1)
        }
    }
}' file
20 m
1/2 kg
5 kg
10 m/s2
```

#### Update: Add more `if` conditions to get your desired result

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/[,.]/,"",$(i+1))
        if($i~/^[[:digit:]]/ && $(i+1)=="m") {
            print "Height = "$i,$(i+1)
        }
        else if($i~/^[[:digit:]]/ && $(i+1)=="kg") {
            print "Mass "++x" = "$i,$(i+1)
        }
        else if($i~/^[[:digit:]]/ && $(i+1)=="m/s2") {
            print "Gravity = "$i,$(i+1)
        }
    }
}' file
Height = 20 m
Mass 1 = 1/2 kg
Mass 2 = 5 kg
Gravity = 10 m/s2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. All solved just in seconds! Amazing. What is the meaning of gsub? And in brief, what is the logics so you can create this code? I have thought for 3 weeks but my result is only on my first question.

Comment: You're welcome. `gsub` in a built-in `awk` function that allows you to make substitutions. As the name suggestions `g` in `gsub` is to do multiple substitutions. I added that portion since there were `,` and `.` attach to our fields (e.g. m, in 20 m,). This helped in removing that from your output.

Comment: Logic used was that every field starting with a digit is our assumed capture and every text following the digit is the metric for that digit. So using `for loop` we iterated over each field and captured the one with digit and the next one assuming it was metric.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Actually I have created at first attempt similiar code as you given above, using for. But I failed, so you helped me. Before admin close this thread, how to give reputation for you? I am new in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
BEGIN { FS = "[ .,]"}
      {
            for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                 if ($i ~ /[0-9]/){
                    print($i, $(++i))
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

```
$awk -f a.awk file
20 m
1/2 kg
5 kg
10 m/s2
```

Comment: Thank you, you use FS declaration rather than gsub() function. It is a good alternative. I accept your solution.